# After Migration from Spock to 2.0 and Groovy to 3.0.7 @Category tests not executed

Tags: groovy, spock, maven-surefire-plugin

**Migrated setup**

Spock version - 2.0-M5-groovy-3.0
jdk version - 11
Maven surefire plugin version - 3.0.0-M5
Maven version - 3.8.0

I have a marker interface and Spock 2.0 tests like below

````
`
interface RestTests {}
`

```
@Category(RestTests)
class SimpleTest extends Specification {

    def "should should” perform simple test”() {
    given:
    // …..
    }
}
```
````

When I run

````
```
./mvnw clean test -Dgroups=com.api.test.categories.RestTests
```

[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:report (jacoco-report)
````

Comment: Do NOT use -Dgroups=com.api.test.categories.RestTests because it is JUnit4 related feature. See the documentation of Surefire first https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html and the documentation for the configuration parameter "groups" https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#groups

Comment: If you want to use groups in JUnit5, you have to read https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html the chapter "Filtering by Tags" and use the annotation @Tag, see https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit-5-tag-annotation-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Category` is a `junit4` feature, Spock 2.0 is a proper `TestEngine` on the JUnit Platform, take a look at [Include and Exclude](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M5/all_in_one.html#_include_and_exclude) of the Spock docs. Hint: it is a groovy file so you can add logic if you need any.

Comment: @leonard84 thank you for the answer, I now understand. Quick clarification, how do I run these config files in the maven command, because I have to run them in my CI pipeline.

Comment: @leonard84 Thank you. The documentation answered all my questions.

Comment: @Denis could you please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use groups in JUnit5, you have to read https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html the chapter "Filtering by Tags" and use the annotation **@Tag**, see https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit-5-tag-annotation-example/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. However, in the end, I wanted to have a purely Spock environment with no JUnit mixture. 
Though I will try out your suggestion in a test environment and see.
Thank you.

Comment: Check it out with my hint. It is the only right solution. I am the developer of Surefire project.